# Sitecore 8.2 error when adding Placeholder

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, sitecore8

I am almost completely new to Sitecore and I was about to try out adding a controller rendering to a demo page I am creating.

I have a main page, with a placeholder for the controller rendering. Placeholder is added to the presentation details of my main page item and accepts the rendering.

When I now go to the experience editor and try to add the controller rendering to the page I get this

```
Error Rendering Controller: SitecoreDemo.Controllers.FoodFinder.PlacesToEatListController, SitecoreDemo. Action: Index: An unhandled exception occurred.
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.ShowErrorMessage(ExceptionContext exceptionContext, ExceptionArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.Process(ExceptionArgs args)
   at (Object , Object[] )
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Filters.PipelineBasedRequestFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext exceptionContext)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.ExecuteController(Controller controller)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerRunner.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ControllerRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)
```

I think this isn't even the full stacktrace but I only see this little box on the page and I don't know how I could even get to the full exception message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was caused by putting the view in the wrong place. If returning a view by convention it's always Views\\.cshtml no matter where the controller is located.

My views were mirroring the namespace structure of the controller which caused ASP.NET MVC to fail finding it by convention (return View(model))

Answer (score 0):

The issue Might be because of the dll referencing the Controller was not in the bin folder. So, please make sure that the assembly referencing the Controller is in the bin folder.

Also, even if the dll is in the bin folder, it may be that it is not being overwritten with the new one. You may try to copy and paste the dll into the bin folder.

Comment: Your answer did point me in the right direction. However, the issue was caused by me placing my view in the wrong folder and calling View(model) in the controller. I am new to ASP.NET MVC conventions